# Update concurrent map inside a stream map on flink

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-flink

I have one stream that constantly streaming the latest values of some keys.

Stream A:`DataStream[(String,Double)]`

I have another stream that wants to get the latest value on each process call.

My approach was to introduce a `concurrentHashMap` which will be updated by stream A and read by the second stream.

```
val rates = new concurrentHasMap[String,Double].asScala
val streamA : DataStream[(String,Double)]= ???
streamA.map(keyWithValue => rates(keyWithValue._1)= keyWithValue._2) //rates never gets updated
rates("testKey")=2 //this works
val streamB: DataStream[String] = ???
streamB.map(str=> rates(str)  // rates does not contain the values of the streamA at this point
  //some other functionality
)
```

Is it possible to update a concurrent map from a stream? Any other solution on sharing data from a stream with another is also acceptable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour You are trying to use will not work in a distributed manner, basically if You will have `parellelism` > 1 it will not work. In Your code `rates` are actually updated, but in different instance of  parallel operator.

Actually, what You would like to do in this case is use a `BroadcastState` which was designed to solve exactly the issue You are facing.

In Your specific usecase it would look like something like this:

```
val streamA : DataStream[(String,Double)]= ???
val streamABroadcasted = streamA.broadcast(<Your Map State Definition>)
val streamB: DataStream[String] = ???
streamB.connect(streamABroadcasted)
```

Then You could easily use `BroadcastProcessFunction` to implement Your logic. More on the Broadcast state pattern can be found [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html)

Comment: thank you this was helpful. After implementing the above pattern I am facing another issue. I would appreciate it if you could have a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239192/apache-flink-broadcast-state-wont-gets-emptied