# Apache flink broadcast state gets flushed

Tags: scala, streaming, state, apache-flink

I am using the broadcast pattern to connect two streams and read data from one to another. The code looks like this

```
case class Broadcast extends BroadCastProcessFunction[MyObject,(String,Double), MyObject]{
  override def processBroadcastElement(in2: (String, Double), 
                                       context: BroadcastProcessFunction[MyObject, (String, Double), MyObject]#Context,
                                       collector:Collector[MyObject]):Unit={
    context.getBroadcastState(broadcastStateDescriptor).put(in2._1,in2._2)
  }

  override def processElement(obj: MyObject,
                            readOnlyContext:BroadCastProcessFunction[MyObject, (String,Double), 
                            MyObject]#ReadOnlyContext, collector: Collector[MyObject]):Unit={
    val theValue = readOnlyContext.getBroadccastState(broadcastStateDesriptor).get(obj.prop)
    //If I print the context of the state here sometimes it is empty.
    out.collect(MyObject(new, properties, go, here))
  }
}
```

The state descriptor:

```
val broadcastStateDescriptor: MapStateDescriptor[String, Double) = new MapStateDescriptor[String, Double]("name_for_this", classOf[String], classOf[Double])
```

My execution code looks like this.

```
val streamA :DataStream[MyObject] = ... 
val streamB :DataStream[(String,Double)] = ... 
val broadcastedStream = streamB.broadcast(broadcastStateDescriptor)

streamA.connect(streamB).process(new Broadcast)
```

The problem is in the `processElement` function the state sometimes is empty and sometimes not. The state should always contain data since I am constantly streaming from a file that I know it has data. I do not understand why it is flushing the state and I cannot get the data.

I tried adding some printing in the `processBroadcastElement` before and after putting the data to the state and the result is the following

```
0 - 1
1 - 2 
2 - 3 
.. all the way to 48 where it resets back to 0
```

UPDATE:
something that I noticed is when I decrease the value of the timeout of the streaming execution context, the results are a bit better. when I increase it then the map is always empty.

```
env.setBufferTimeout(1) //better results 
env.setBufferTimeout(200) //worse result (default is 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David mentioned the job could be restarting. I disabled the checkpoints so I could see any possible exception thrown instead of flink silently failing and restarting the job.

It turned out that there was an error while trying to parse the file. So the job kept restarting thus the state was empty and flink kept consuming the stream over and over again.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem. Looking at the logs (or the checkpointing and uptime/restart metrics) should have revealed this, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever two streams are connected in Flink, you have no control over the timing with which Flink will deliver events from the two streams to your user function. So, for example, if there is an event available to process from streamA, and an event available to process from streamB, either one might be processed next. You cannot expect the broadcastedStream to somehow take precedence over the other stream.

There are various strategies you might employ to cope with this race between the two streams, depending on your requirements. For example, you could use a KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction and use its applyToKeyedState method to iterate over all existing keyed state whenever a new broadcast event arrives.

Comment: but how come the state gets empty? If I let the streams run for a couple of minutes then I would expect the state to be constantly full right? That's not the case though. it looks like that the state gets reset.

Comment: If you share more of the code it might be possible to understand what your app is doing.

Comment: The broadcast state is a Map -- when you say it is empty, do you mean there is no value for a particular key that you expect to have a value, or that there are no keys with values whatsoever?

Comment: I mean that there are no keys with values. the map is completely empty. That's what makes me curious. Is there an expiry time on the map? shouldn't the map be full all the time after it reads  the broadcasted stream?

Comment: something that I noticed is when I decrease the number timeout value of the streaming execution context, the results are a bit better. when I increase it then the map is always empty.
`env.setBufferTimeout(1)` //better results
`env.setBufferTimeout(200)` //worse results

Comment: Once the state for a given key is set, it should persist until it is cleared. Could it be that checkpointing is disabled, and the job is restarting?

Comment: The fact that the timing makes a difference suggests that your application is non-deterministic, and that the inherent race condition between the broadcast and non-broadcast streams is affecting the results.

Comment: I did not understand the last comment. could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm suggesting that perhaps the method printing out the map is sometimes scheduled to run before the method that receives the broadcast events. It appears empty because it is being viewed before it is filled.

Comment: I am getting the hint that the map is empty also when I print the stream at the very end of the computations. by doing `finalStream.print`, I just let my app run for 5 minutes and out of the 2000 processed elements, 500 of them did not find anything in the map . Also checkpointing is enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193757/discussion-between-david-anderson-and-dionysis-nt).